# SearchView as query JSON

Tags: android, android-actionbar

So, I want to make a query to `JSON` with `"SearchView"` in Actionbar but `SearchView` is for Search as the name suggests.

I mean to get the symbolic appearance and the possibility to transfer data from them after the assignment of items to the variables (`EditText`, `Button`)

I searched the web on this subject but found nothing.

I have basic layout with this view :

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
       android:id="@+id/menu_search"
       android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
       android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
       android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
       android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

Java :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
           SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
           inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_in_menu, menu);
           return true;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

(I'm a beginner)

Comment: You are on the right track. There is a good tutorial on this subject [here](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/action-bar-search-view/). Also on the [android dev website](http://developer.android.com/training/search/index.html) there are a few pages on the topic.